# OBS NVENC Doesn't work Out of Box on 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, 20.04, obs-studio

I just installed Kubuntu 20.04 and OBS,but NVENC doesn't seem to work for some reason even though I have `nvidia-driver-390` installed and configured via `System Settings`.

**Settings:**

[image: Settings]

**Error on `Start Recording`:**

[image: Error]

**System Settings:**

[image: System Settings]

How can I restore OBS's hardware NVENC support?

Hardware Specs:

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: LesserArk Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ENVY 17 Notebook PC v: 097E110000405E00000620100 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1968 v: KBC Version 93.52 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Insyde v: F.70 
           date: 10/20/2017 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 41.2 Wh condition: 41.2/41.2 Wh (100%) model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-4702MQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 35120 
           Speed: 2050 MHz min/max: 800/3200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2050 2: 2152 3: 2027 4: 2090 5: 2067 6: 2128 7: 1956 
           8: 2096 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nvidia v: 390.132 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~75Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.132 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-31-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: wlp7s0 state: up mac: e4:70:b8:f8:99:b8 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 0f:00.0 
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0 
           IF-ID-1: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 3.21 TiB used: 1.18 TiB (36.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: LITE-ON IT model: LMS-24L6M-HP size: 22.37 GiB 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM015-2E8174 size: 1.82 TiB 
           ID-4: /dev/sdd vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
           ID-5: /dev/sde type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: U3 Cruzer Micro size: 1.91 GiB 
           ID-6: /dev/sdf type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Gaming Xbox 360 size: 7.48 GiB 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:1f.2 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 398.61 GiB used: 208.93 GiB (52.4%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sdd2 
           ID-2: /home size: 398.61 GiB used: 208.93 GiB (52.4%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sdd2 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 14.90 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdd3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 63.0 C mobo: 60.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 55 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 466 Uptime: 1h 34m Memory: 15.57 GiB used: 7.12 GiB (45.7%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried the open source one?

Comment: @Chris Do you mean the Nouveau driver? I haven't yet.

Comment: Correct. Can you try that for a sec.? NVidia drivers are widelyknown for their compability issues tho, so i think the open source might have better chance.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a fresh machine last night. I did not install an NVidia driver from the NVidia website but rather used the one provided as additional drivers like you did

[image]

The OBS installation was done as outlined in the [installation steps on the wiki](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#ubuntu-installation), which means first installing FFmpeg and then adding the obs ppa.
Here, NVENC is working out of the box.

In the past on Ubuntu 16.04, I had to compile everything myself (FFmpeg and all its dependencies and then obs) to get NVENC working. The versions I'm using right now are

```
ffmpeg/focal,now 7:4.2.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
obs-studio/focal,now 25.0.8-0obsproject1~focal amd64 [installed]
```

The difference I notice is that I'm using a more recent NVidia driver. Maybe this helps you to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only installed this package and it works now.

```
sudo apt-get install libffmpeg-nvenc-dev
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.

Comment: What did work in installing the "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)". In other words, the non-open version.

Answer (score -1):

I was strugling with the same issues.
To me, with a I7 processor (intel) and a GeForce 210 installed, I realised that was in use the 340 nvec driver. So, I removed it and tryed to install the 390 one. After restart the machine all was very easy and worked properly. But, this is very strange I know, if I get the new machine informations, I realised that is in use the Xserver-Xorg-video-noveau (open-source) driver!!
So, the mistery is going on, but at this time, I'm happy ('cause I can now make the good use of OBS software).
Pazigrafio